# How do I match two consecutive dynamic parameters in react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create my routes hierarchy in react router v6 so that I can render two unknown, dynamically generated parameters (:*project-Id* and :*todo-Id*) one after the other:

```
/listProjects /:project-Id /listTodos /:todo-Id
```

I need to match both /:projectId and /:todoId exactly so that they render different components every time the url is matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this with the [useRoutes](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#useroutes) hook in react-router-v6, you can define a route config for the above as a standard JS object:

```
import { Outlet, useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {

  const routesElement = useRoutes([
        {
          path: "/projects",
          element: <Outlet />,
          children: [
            { path: "/", element: <ListProjects /> },
            {
              path: "/:id",
              children: [
                {
                  path: "/",
                  element: <SpecificProjectWhereTodosAreListed />,
                },
                { path: "/:id", element: <SpecificTodoWithinThisProject /> },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },       
  ]);


  return routesElement
};

export default App;
```

Note the use of the `<Outlet />` component ([reference in docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#outlet)) from react-router-v6 on the top level that determines which of the children routes are matched and therefore which react component gets rendered each time (if routes after `<ListProject />` need to match exactly and only render one react component each time).